# How to add self-created text fields on android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have created a Plain text through `Ai`, now i want to use it in android studio but don't know how to?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I will provide my code but my concern is about concept of how to add custom palettes(like for button:- image button is there so that user can create their own buttons and display them). I hope you understand.